# CCAnimation and CCAnimate leak?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In my @Monster class, there are 3 different walk animation.

"Monster.h"

```
@interface Monster : CCSprite{
   CCAction *fWalk;
   CCAction *bWalk;
   CCAction *hWalk;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAction *fWalk;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAction *bWalk;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAction *hWalk;
```

"Monster.m"

```
+ (id) monsterInit...
{
    Monster *sprite = ...// initialization

    NSMutableArray *frameArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormation:@"%d.png", i];
        [frameArray addObject[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:fileName]];
    }
    CCAnimation *walk = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:frameArray delay:0.1f];
    self.fWalk = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walk restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];

    [frameArray removeAllObjects];
    for ( int i = 3; i < 6; i++ ) {
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormation:@"%d.png", i];
        [frameArray addObject[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:fileName]];
    }
    walk = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:frameArray delay:0.1f];
    sprite.bWalk = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walk restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];

    [frameArray removeAllObjects];
    for ( int i = 6; i < 9; i++ ) {
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormation:@"%d.png", i];
        [frameArray addObject[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:fileName]];
    }
    walk = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:frameArray delay:0.1f];
    sprite.hWalk = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walk restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];

    return sprite;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [fWalk release];
    [bWalk release];
    [hWalk release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

When I run this app with performance tool - Leaks. Instruments display statement which is "CCAnimation *walk...", "self.fWalk...", "walk = ...", "self.bWalk...", "walk = ...", "self.hWalk.." induce memory leaks.

I checked source code about CCAnimation and CCAnimate, they are all "autorelease".I don't know why this leaks happened.
Any idea on what to do?

Answer (score 2):

You have to retain the actions if you plan to use them later, because they are autoreleased when created with the actionWithAction method. Like this:

```
self.fWalk = [[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walk restoreOriginalFrame:NO]] retain];
```

Otherwise, your monster class doesn't own the actions and they are autoreleased when you leave the init method.

Answer (score 1):

Ok but when you save all animations into an Array like this:

```
CCAnimation *anim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animFrames delay:pDelay];
CCAnimate *animate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim];
CCCallFunc *callback = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:pTarget selector:pCallBack];
CCSequence *seq = [CCSequence actions:animate, callback , nil];

NSMutableDictionary *animations;

[animations setValue:seq forKey:pName];

- (void)dealloc {
    for (NSString* key in [animations allKeys]) {
        CCAction *action = [animations objectForKey:key];
        [self stopAction:action];
        [action stop];
    }

    [animations removeAllObjects];
    //[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];
}
```

The CCAnimation is not release...